# Size of tablefooter not increasing in uitableview

Tags: iphone, uitableview, footer

The size of the table footer is not increasing, it seems like it is fixed by default. How can we change it ?
I am using the below mentioned code for this but it is not working. Can anyone help me in this ? Thanks in Advance.

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    UIView *view = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 200)] autorelease];
    view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"blue-bg.jpg"]];
    return view;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 50;
}
```

Comment: Thanks it means i have to use both methods, but i want to have the clear color of footer so that tableview background color can be seen.

Comment: I know that, it is not working. Actually i have defined my tableview frame (10, 20, 300, 460), and also set image to classview and same image to tableview, used clearcolor but not working.

Answer (score 1):

In your .h file where you confirm to the UITableViewDelegate, You can press the command button and then click on UITableViewDelegate and it will take you to the protocol where you can find all the relevant methods that you can use to customize your table view.
And yes the way how to do it is already being answered. Good luck!! Cheers!!